# How to predict the length of a string encoded with base64 from a float32 numpy array, without knowing the string itself but only the array shape?

Tags: python, numpy, base64

Suppose I have a numpy array, of which I know the shape and that its dtype is float32.   How could I calculate the base64 encoding of the array?

Example:

```
In [36]:  a=np.array([1,2,3],dtype=float)


In [38]: b=base64.b64encode(a).decode("ascii")    ####encode np array to str

In [39]: b
Out[39]: 'AAAAAAAA8D8AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAhA'
```

How could I **predict** the length of `b` without actually computing b,  given the shape and dtype of `a`(float32)?

Comment: Without actually computing `b`?

Comment: @ScottHunter Right. Without computing `b`.

Comment: For which `dtype`s?  For example, you're out of luck if `dtype=str`.

Comment: @ScottHunter That is a great concern. I realize my data are float32 so I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Try printing the length of encoding for a series of different shaped arrays (content doesn't matter); you might discern a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

base64 will use roughly a size proportional to the input array, however there is padding, to in practice each item will use 12 characters, except the last one it the length is a multiple of 3.

You can use the following function to compute the number of characters from the float array length:

```
def b64len(l):
    return 12*l - (0 if l%3 else 4*(l//3))

a = np.array([1,2,3],dtype=float)
b64len(len(a))
# 32
```

Comment: Not sure. But len(np.random.rand(3,5)) = len(np.random.rand(3,2)) = 3, meaning the two have the same size (as base64 string) following your formula.

Comment: Yes the two have the same size with your base64 conversion